# Como ajustar o tamanho de uma imagem no Flutter

Tags: flutter

Estou desenvolvendo um app no Flutter e na homepage estou tentando criar vários widgets que serão botões que encaminharão para outras págias. Estou com dúvida de como posso utilizar o  'width e height' na imagem.

```dart
body: Column(
  children: <Widget>[ const SizedBox(height: 20),
  Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Flexible(
        flex: 5,
        child:
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {Navigator.of(context) .push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (
                  context,
                )
                => const TelaInicial()
              )
            ) ;},
            child:
              Container(
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(
                    image: const
                      DecorationImage(
                        image:
                          NetworkImage(
                            "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/553/553416.png"
                          )
                      ),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black12,
                        blurRadius: 10,
                        offset: Offset(0, 10)
                      ),
                    ]
                  ),
                child: const
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child:
                      Text(
                        "Meu Ponto",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)
                      )
                  )
              )
          )
      ),
    const Spacer(),
    Flexible(
      flex: 5,
      child:
        Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          decoration:
            BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  offset: Offset(0, 10)
                ),
              ]
            )
        ),
    ),
    const Spacer(),
    Flexible(
      flex: 5,
      child:
        Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          decoration:
            BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  offset: Offset(0, 10)
                ),
              ]
            )
        ),
    ),
    ],
  ),
  const SizedBox(height: 20),
  Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Flexible(
        flex: 5,
        child:
          Container(
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
            decoration:
              BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black12,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    offset: Offset(0, 10)
                  ),
                ]
              )
          )
      ),
    const Spacer(),
    Flexible(
      flex: 5,
      child:
        Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          decoration:
            BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  offset: Offset(0, 10)
                ),
              ]
            )
        ),
    ),
    const Spacer(),
    Flexible(
      flex: 5,
      child:
        Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 150,
          decoration:
            BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black12,
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  offset: Offset(0, 10)
                ),
              ]
            )
        ),
    ),
    ],
  ),
  ]
);
```

Na imagem está como está agora e gostaria que ele ficasse com metade do tamanho.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Você utilizou a propriedade `BoxDecoration` do `Container` e colocou uma `DecorationImage` nele.

Isso significa que o `Container` em si vai ter essa imagem como fundo. Como eles estão em dois níveis diferentes, vai ficar complicado você limitar o tamanho dela ou então fazê-la interagir corretamente com o `Text` que está como filho do `Container`.

Acredito que sua intenção é que esse Container tenha na verdade dois filhos: O ícone, e o texto embaixo. Isso pode ser alcançado com uma `Column`. No seu exemplo, ficaria:

```
Container(
              height: 150.0,
              width: 150.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black12,
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    offset: Offset(0, 10),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/553/553416.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Meu Ponto',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Que tem como resultado:

[image: Resultado final]

Isso não é exatamente "metade do tamanho" como você descreveu na pergunta, porém, qualquer alteração de tamanho ou outra personalização pode ser feita diretamente no Image Widget em questão. (Você pode por exemplo envolvê-la em outro Container e limitar sua altura/largura, pode mudar a propriedade `flex` do Expanded, entre outras opções.)

Lembre-se de envolver a imagem em um [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) para a imagem saber quanto de espaço ela tem disponível. Se você não fizer isso, o conteúdo da `Column` irá crescer mais do que o height que você especificou para o `Container`.

Para maiores informações sugiro consultar a documentação oficial ou alguns dos cookbooks que eles dão de exemplo